# In HPCC ECL, when running a LOCAL, LOOKUP JOIN. Does the RHS dataset gets copied to all nodes, or kept distributed due to LOCAL?

Tags: hpcc-ecl

Say I have a cluster of 400 machines, and 2 datasets. some_dataset_1 has 100M records, some_dataset_2 has 1M. I then run:

ds1:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_1,hash(field_**a**));
ds2:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_2,hash(field_**b**));

Then, I run the join:

j1:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.field_a=LEFT.field_b,**LOOKUP,LOCAL**);

Will the distribution of ds2 "mess up" the join, meaning parts of ds2 will be incorrectly scattered across the cluster leading to low match rate?

Or, will the LOOKUP keyword take precedence and the distributed ds2 will get copied in full to each node, thus rendering the distribution irrelevant, and allowing the join to find all the possible matches (as each node will have a full copy of ds2).

I know I can test this myself and come to my own conclusion, but I am looking for a definitive answer based on the way the language is written to make sure I understand and can use these options correctly.

For reference (from the Language Reference document v 7.0.0):
**LOOKUP**: Specifies the rightrecset is a relatively small file of lookup records that *can be fully copied to every node*.
**LOCAL**: Specifies the operation is performed on each supercomputer node independently, without requiring interaction with all other nodes to acquire data; *the operation maintains the distribution* of any previous DISTRIBUTE

It seems that with the LOCAL, the join completes more quickly. There does not seem to be a loss of matches on initial trials. I am working with others to run a more thorough test and will post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code:

ds1:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_1,hash(field_a));

ds2:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_2,hash(field_b));

Since you're intending these results to be used in a JOIN, it is imperative that both datasets are distributed on the "same" data, so that the matching values end up on the same nodes so that your JOIN can be done with the LOCAL option. So this will only work correctly if ds1.field_a and ds2.field_b contain the "same" data.

Then, your join code. I assume you've made a typo in this post, because your join code needs to be (to work at all):

j1:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.field_a=**RIGHT**.field_b,LOOKUP,LOCAL);

Using both LOOKUP and LOCAL options is redundant because a LOOKUP JOIN is implicitly a LOCAL operation. That means, your LOOKUP option does "override" the LOCAL in this insatnce.

So, all that means that you should either do it this way:

ds1:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_1,hash(field_a));

ds2:=DISTRIBUTE(some_dataset_2,hash(field_b));

j1:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.field_a=RIGHT.field_b,LOCAL);

Or this way:

j1:=JOIN(some_dataset_1,some_dataset_2,LEFT.field_a=RIGHT.field_b,LOOKUP);

Because the LOOKUP option does copy the entire right-hand dataset (in memory) to every node, it makes the JOIN implicitly a LOCAL operation and you do not need to do the DISTRIBUTEs. Which way you choose to do it is up to you.

However, I see from your Language Reference version that you may be unaware of the SMART option on JOIN, which in my current Language Reference (8.10.10) says:

> SMART -- Specifies to use an in-memory lookup when possible, but use a
> distributed join if the right dataset is large.

So you could just do it this way:

j1:=JOIN(some_dataset_1,some_dataset_2,LEFT.field_a=RIGHT.field_b,SMART);

and let the platform figure out which is best.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: Thank you @Richard, please see my additional answer based on my own testing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Richard. Yes, I am notorious for typo's. I apologize. As I use a lot of legacy code, I have not had a chance to work with the SMART option, but I will certainly keep that in mine for me and the team, - so thank you for that!

However, I did run a test to evaluate how the compiler and the platform would handles this scenario. I ran the following code:

```
sd1:=DATASET(100000,TRANSFORM({unsigned8 num1},SELF.num1 := COUNTER  ));
sd2:=DATASET(1000,TRANSFORM({unsigned8 num1, unsigned8 num2},SELF.num1 := COUNTER , SELF.num2 := COUNTER % 10 ));

ds1:=DISTRIBUTE(sd1,hash(num1));
ds4:=DISTRIBUTE(sd1,random());
ds2:=DISTRIBUTE(sd2,hash(num1));
ds3:=DISTRIBUTE(sd2,hash(num2));

j11:=JOIN(sd1,sd2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1             ):independent;
j12:=JOIN(sd1,sd2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP      ):independent;
j13:=JOIN(sd1,sd2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,       LOCAL):independent;
j14:=JOIN(sd1,sd2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP,LOCAL):independent;

j21:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1             ):independent;
j22:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP      ):independent;
j23:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,       LOCAL):independent;
j24:=JOIN(ds1,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP,LOCAL):independent;

j31:=JOIN(ds1,ds3,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1             ):independent;
j32:=JOIN(ds1,ds3,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP      ):independent;
j33:=JOIN(ds1,ds3,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,       LOCAL):independent;
j34:=JOIN(ds1,ds3,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP,LOCAL):independent;

j41:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1             ):independent;
j42:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP      ):independent;
j43:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,       LOCAL):independent;
j44:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP,LOCAL):independent;

j51:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1             ):independent;
j52:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP      ):independent;
j53:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,       LOCAL,HASH):independent;
j54:=JOIN(ds4,ds2,LEFT.num1=RIGHT.num1,LOOKUP,LOCAL,HASH):independent;

dataset([{count(j11),'11'},{count(j12),'12'},{count(j13),'13'},{count(j14),'14'},
         {count(j21),'21'},{count(j22),'22'},{count(j23),'23'},{count(j24),'24'},
         {count(j31),'31'},{count(j32),'32'},{count(j33),'33'},{count(j34),'34'},
         {count(j31),'41'},{count(j32),'42'},{count(j33),'43'},{count(j44),'44'},
         {count(j51),'51'},{count(j52),'52'},{count(j53),'53'},{count(j54),'54'}
         
        ] , {unsigned8 num, string lbl});
```

On a 400 node cluster, the results come back as:

| ## | num | lbl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 11 |
| 2 | 1000 | 12 |
| 3 | 1000 | 13 |
| 4 | 1000 | 14 |
| 5 | 1000 | 21 |
| 6 | 1000 | 22 |
| 7 | 1000 | 23 |
| 8 | 1000 | 24 |
| 9 | 1000 | 31 |
| 10 | 1000 | 32 |
| 11 | 12 | 33 |
| 12 | 12 | 34 |
| 13 | 1000 | 41 |
| 14 | 1000 | 42 |
| 15 | 12 | 43 |
| 16 | 6 | 44 |
| 17 | 1000 | 51 |
| 18 | 1000 | 52 |
| 19 | 1 | 53 |
| 20 | 1 | 54 |

If you look at the row 12 in the result ( lbl 34 ), you will notice the match rate drops substantially, suggesting the compiler does indeed distribute the file (with the wrong hashed field) and disregard the LOOKUP option.

My conclusion is therefore that as always, it remains the developer's responsibility to ensure the distribution is right ahead of the join REGARDLESS of which join options are being used.

Comment: If you modify the j34 definition and reverse the order (make it LOCAL,LOOKUP instead) does it change the behavior?

Comment: No. It makes no difference. The results are the same regardless of the order of the options

Answer (score 1):

The manual page could be better. **LOOKUP** by itself is properly documented. and **LOCAL** by itself is properly documented. However, they represent two different concepts and can be combined without issue so that **JOIN(,,, LOOKUP, LOCAL)** makes sense and can be useful.

It is probably best to consider **LOOKUP** as a specific kind of **JOIN** matching algorithm and to consider **LOCAL** as a way to tell the compiler that you are not a novice and that you are absolutely sure the data is already where it needs to be to accomplish what you intend.

For a normal **LOOKUP** join the LEFT-hand side doesn't need to be sorted or distributed in any particular way and the whole RHS-hand side is copied to every slave. No matter what join value appears on the LEFT, if there is a matching value on the RIGHT then it will be found because the whole RIGHT dataset is present.

In a 400-way system with well-distributed join values, IF the LEFT side is distributed on the join value, then the LEFT dataset in each worker only contains 1/400th of the join values and only 1/400th of the values in the RIGHT dataset will ever be matched. Effectively, within each worker, 399/400th of the RIGHT data will be unused.

However, if both the LEFT and RIGHT datasets are distributed on the join value ... and you are not a novice and know that using LOCAL is what you want ... then you can specify a **LOOKUP**, **LOCAL** join. The RIGHT data is already where it needs to be. Any join value that appears in the LEFT data will, if the value exists, find a match locally in the RIGHT dataset. As a bonus, the RIGHT data only contains join values that could match ... it is only 1/400th of the **LOOKUP** only size.

This enables larger **LOOKUP** joins. Imagine your 400-way system and a 100GB RIGHT dataset that you would like to use in a **LOOKUP** join. Copying a 100GB dataset to each slave seems unlikely to work. However, if evenly distributed, a **LOOKUP**, **LOCAL** join only requires 250MB of RIGHT data per worker ... which seems quite reasonable.

HTH